# jquery ui sortable saving connectWith lists to mysql database php

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, jquery-ui

I have two lists

```
<ul class="sortable" id="list-A">
   <li id="1">Value 1 </li>
   <li id="2">Value 2 </li>
   <li id="3">Value 3 </li>
</ul>

<ul class="sortable" id="list-B">
   <li id="4">Value 1 </li>
   <li id="5">Value 2 </li>
   <li id="6">Value 3 </li>
</ul>
```

connected like this

```
     $( ".sortable" ).sortable({
       connectWith: '.sortable',
       placeholder: "widget-highlight"
     });
```

i knew how to save a one ordered list to database by saving the order
but **how to save if the user moves an item from list a to list b** ?

i want to save the item position but how

Comment: What position do you want to save? The item's new position in list B?

Comment: if item moved from list A to list B the item should be saved in list B and vice versa

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `.sortable()`'s `.receive()` callback, get the dropped node's `.index()` via `ui.item.index()`.  How you process it in PHP will depend on how your ajax handler is setup.

```
$( ".sortable" ).sortable({
   connectWith: '.sortable',
   placeholder: "widget-highlight",
   // Receive callback
   receive: function(event, ui) {
     // The position where the new item was dropped
     var newIndex = ui.item.index();
     // Do some ajax action...
     $.post('someurl.php', {newPosition: newIndex}, function(returnVal) {
        // Stuff to do on AJAX post success
     });
   },
   // Likewise, use the .remove event to *delete* the item from its origin list
   remove: function(event, ui) {
     var oldIndex = ui.item.index();
     $.post('someurl.php', {deletedPosition: oldIndex}, function(returnVal) {
        // Stuff to do on AJAX post success
     });

   }
 });
```

The above example will send the dropped node's new list position in `$_POST['newPosition']`

The events are fully described in the [`.sortable()` API documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-receive)